# phpmyadmin automatic logout time

Tags: php, mysql, database, cookies, phpmyadmin

How can I change the phpmyadmin automatic log out time?

It will log out automatically after 1440 seconds which is very low for me.  How can I change the option or remove log in request completely?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Create or edit your `php.ini` file and set this variable value in it:

`session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`

The integer is in seconds.  500000 seconds is 5.7 days.  Then restart apache.

Comment: Thanks but I am working in localhost and have access to all files and settings

Comment: so open your php.ini file and increase the value of session.gc_maxlifetime, that's it.

Comment: bad answer, security issues!

Comment: You may also need to update $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] in the phpmyadmin config.inc.php file.

Comment: @slaver113 In this case I'd say the security is fine as it's a development environment, this is NOT fine for any production environment. I'd prefer to see this mentioned in the answer.

Comment: hs no clickpath to follow like: PHPMyAdmin in your browser > Settings > Features > Change the value of 'Login cookie validity' > Save

Comment: @php_purest should I still modify `session.gc_maxlifetime` value ?

Comment: I believe what I was trying to say was there's 2 main ways to do the same thing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin's timeout. I don't know why it's so highly voted. It's not even related to the question.

Comment: In fact it appears you have to set both `session.gc_maxlifetime` **and** `LoginCookieValidity` (see below).  As for it being a "security issue" (slaver113): er, yes, you do this for your development server, not your production server.  Perhaps some people here already knew that.

Comment: Does it only effects to the phpmyadmin or else all the sessions life times available in the same host?

Answer (score 122):

Changing php.ini will change the session duration for all the websites running on the server. To change it just for PhpMyAdmin, open `config.inc.php` and add:

```
$sessionDuration = 60*60*24*7; // 60*60*24*7 = one week
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $sessionDuration);
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = $sessionDuration;
```

Comment: there seems to be UI for setting config.php variables at http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php?page=form&formset=Features#tab_Security - see Login Cookie Validity

Comment: This UI setting is a bit confusing but works for setting password in config for automatic login and set session expiration time. Upvote.

Comment: but can't set cookie to unlimited time(0)

Comment: Unlimited time is kind of impossible because every cookie has a "Valid Until"-Date, but you can just enter a very high number.

Comment: This should be the answer. The question asked how to modify phpMyAdmin. This answer solves it specifically.

Comment: You need to change cookie path too. Because if gc_maxlifetime is defined for an other website, the gc will delete all cookies the first time it is call for a website. You can add these 2 lines in the /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf file : php_admin_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800  +
        php_admin_value session.save_path /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp

Comment: I always forget the path -> `sudo gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` for ubuntu / gnome

Comment: /etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php in arch linux

Comment: @fred727 can you pls expand on your comment - maybe post it as another answer? Should your lines be placed next to the other `php_admin_value` lines?

Comment: If I try to use init_set, phpmyadmin does not load . no error, no nothing .
If I dont set it, only $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'], I get a message : "Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login might expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin." . But, it seems to work anyway. php7.4, apache 2.4 pma 5, mariadb 10.4 on mac os 10.14 ! if  $cfg['LoginCookieValidityDisableWarning'] = true, the message won't show up anymore !

Comment: @psycho brm: when I call this page, I get the following errormessage: "Configuration already exists, setup is disabled!".  For sure you mean this page: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/preferences/features.
In general, laurent's answer doesn't seem so wrong. The documentation seems to confirm this, if I see it correctly: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/release_5_2_0/config.html#config

Answer (score 109):

In PHPMyAdmin 4 this no longer appears in the config.inc.php file. Instead go to PHPMyAdmin in your browser. Ensure you are at the localhost level to see the Settings link. Then set Settings > Features > Change the value of 'Login cookie validity' > Save

[image: instructions]

Comment: N.B. there appears to be a limit on how many characters you can enter in this field.

Comment: The UI change doesn't work for me. It still log out too quickly, no matter how bigger the *Login cookie validity* is.

Comment: @dani24, did you get this notice: `Your preferences will be saved for current session only. Storing them permanently requires phpMyAdmin configuration storage.`? Click the link in this, and it will give you instructions for enabling the ability to permanently store changes.

Comment: phpMyAdmin will show this error. `Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.` You will have to apply Ravinder Singh's answer as well as this one.

Comment: Not available in version 4.8.4

Comment: This generates a warning by PHPmyAdmin if the session.gc_maxlifetime is set lower.

Answer (score 13):

You can change the cookie time session feature at phpmyadmin web interface

```
Settings->Features->General->Login cookie validity
```

OR

If you want to change the 'login cookie validity' in configuration file, then open the phpmMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php` in the root directory of PHPMyAdmin.(root directory is usually /etc/phpmyadmin/)

After locating the config.inc.php , search for the line below and set it to the value of seconds you want phpmyadmin to timeout:

```
['LoginCookieValidity']
```

If you couldn't find the above line, just add the following:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = <your_new_timeout>;
```

For example:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 3;
```

The Timeout is set to 3 Hours from the Example above.

`session.gc_maxlifetime` might limit session validity and if the session is lost, the login cookie is also invalidated. So, we may need to set the session.gc_maxlifetime in `php.ini` configuration file(file location is  /etc/php5 /apache2/php.ini in ubuntu).

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600 * 3
```

---

**[phpMyAdmin Documentation on LoginCookieValidity](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieValidity)**

$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']

Type:   *integer [number of seconds]*
Default value:  *1440*

Define how long a login cookie is valid. Please note that php configuration option session.gc_maxlifetime might limit session validity and if the session is lost, the login cookie is also invalidated. So it is a good idea to set session.gc_maxlifetime at least to the same value of $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'].

*NOTE:*

1. If your server crashed and cannot load your phpmyadmin page, check
   your apache log at /var/log/apache2/error.log. If you got `PHP Fatal
   error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
   /path/to/phpmyadmin/libraries/Header.class.php` on line 135, then do
   a `chmod 644 config.inc.php`. that should take care of the error.
2. If you get the warning: `Your PHP parameter
   session.gc_maxlifetime is lower that cookie validity configured in
   phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than
   configured in phpMyAdmin.`, then change the `session.gc_maxlifetime`
   as mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

For LOCAL installs only, you can remove the login and timeout altogether - this seems to be what you're after. By changing the authorization type to "config" and entering your database username and password in your config file you are automatically logged in. Add to `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'username';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Of-course if you do this on a server on the internet, some cheeky chappy will come along and gleefully download all your passwords and delete your website. This is for a development server running on your own laptop only.

An easier way to customise phpmyadmin these days is to go to http://www.example.com/phpmyadmin/setup/ , save all your settings section at a time, click save or download at the bottom, copy the file generated to your root phpmyadmin directory, then chmod it. You have to turn off write permission even if it is a local server as phpmyadmin checks this before it lets yo log in.

Comment: The file name is wrong, not a big issue as most will understand what you mean. The correct name nevertheless is `config.inc.php`

Answer (score 3):

Explore directory 'apps\phpmyadmin4.5.2' in your wamp folder and open config.inc.php file. Then add this line under existing  code.

```
'$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600 * 10; //login cookie validity extended upto 10 hours'.
```

That's all...

Answer (score 2):

For `phpMyadmin` **5.0.2** running on Ubuntu 18.04, I edited the file as follows:

1. `sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/Config/Forms/User/FeaturesForm.php`
2. find the method `public static function getForms()` and added **LoginCookieValidity** field

   ```
   public static function getForms()
   {
       $result = [
           'General' => [
               'VersionCheck',
               'NaturalOrder',
               'InitialSlidersState',
               'LoginCookieValidity', //Added this line if it missing
               ...........
         }
   ```
3. save the file and now you will be able to change the value from user interface.

**[Settings -> General -> Features -> Login Cookie Validatity]**

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking at the answers above, and back at my 5.0.2 installation, and thinking I was losing my mind! Wonder why they removed the UI, especially if it's still there ready to be reenabled?

Answer (score 0):

`Server:localhost -> Settings -> Features -> General -> Login cookie validity`

Comment: The same answer was already posted long time ago (and with explanation + information about the php session timeout which your answer lacks).

Comment: Although I didnt mention, I always prefer super simple answers for some type of questions.

Comment: Yes, but if you set login cookie validity to higher value than the session validity in php, it won't work.

Comment: I did'nt know that. thanks for your informative comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I have phpmyadmin 4.9.2. and try to config LoginCookieValidity, but I have auto logout :(
If you using localhost you can try https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#example-for-ip-address-limited-autologin

```
if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "127.0.0.1") {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';
} else {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
}
```