# How to set connection timeout value for pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin to connect remotely to my database as phpPgAdmin is a bit limited in its features. Only problem is if I leave the SQL window open without running a query for a few minutes, then it says I need to reconnect.

Is this a setting I need to change in my database to keep remote connections alive for longer or is it a pgAdmin setting?

Answer (score 3):

It is client setting. 
You need specify connect_timeout in your config file.
[29.1. Database Connection Control Functions](http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.6/pg/libpq.html)
[29.14. The Connection Service File](http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.6/pg/libpq-pgservice.html)

Comment: I can't find a pg_service.conf file anywhere :(

Comment: Sorry. This config for pgAdmin. You can find sample file in following path: /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/pg_service.conf.sample

For PhpPgAdmin most probably the problem is PHP session expiration. Please check
settings in your php.ini file:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php
Pay attention to session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime directives.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure this out. Can you specify in the answer where I need to make an edit in order to extend the default connect_timeout setting for a database connection in pgadmin?

Comment: Please check [automatic logout time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272973/phpmyadmin-automatic-logout-time) this is the similar problem.