# How to set connection timeout for pgAdmin 4

Tags: pgadmin

I have read the article listed here:

[How to set connection timeout value for pgAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090683/how-to-set-connection-timeout-value-for-pgadmin)

many times, but I still have no idea where one sets the config parameter for connection_timeout. I am connecting from a local host to a local host, so there should be no real problems with keep alives.

I would like to know the path to:

1. The server setting if that is where it needs to be set
2. the location for a client config (if that is where it is set)
3. What the exact values that have to be put in for that.

I see others are also confused:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97534/is-there-a-timeout-option-for-remote-access-to-postgresql-database

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61193/how-to-edit-postgresql-conf-with-pgadmin

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan yes, that is the way to get to the configuration. But what parameter does one change in the postgresql.conf ? And what does one set it to? And why is this a server-wide setting, and not a client setting?

Comment: i can give the last question answer , because if it is clientside there is a chance that client connection  will never  time out .. therefore this control is with the server so that it can dynamicaly adjust the timeout time according to the stress on server

Comment: at last find the document https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan, FYI, PGADMIN 4 no longer has a TOOLS-> Server Config

Comment: i think i can't help you ...

Comment: @Dr.YSG Can you ask on one of the Postgres mailing lists? Maybe the developers and other experienced users can help out. There is anecdotal evidence that this feature doesn't always help.

Comment: any progress on this? I currently have a timeout to my db using pgadmin4 and nginx proxy - but everything else works fine. Is this an nginx conf?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is useful. It is from [the documentation](https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.10/docs/pgadmin4-4.10.pdf):

"The [runtime] configuration settings are stored using the QSettings class in Qt, which will use
- an INI file on Unix systems (`~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf`)
- a plist file on Mac OS X (`~/Library/Preferences/org.pgadmin.pgadmin4.plist`)
- and the registry on Windows (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\pgadmin\pgadmin4`)."

[image: table]

The documentation also mentions 3 other configuration files in the section immediately preceding this one.