# what is the default session time in PHP and how can I change it?

Tags: php, mysql, session, phpmyadmin

I try to change the session timeout in php so how it's possible.
and What is the default session timeout value in PHP?
I work on my XAMP localhost for development everyday.

I feel annoyed by phpmyadmin auto log out out quickly. Is there any way I change the session timeout?

Where can I set this timeout value?

Comment: how much you set in php.ini file

Comment: @AmitGaud 30 minutes

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272973/phpmyadmin-automatic-logout-time) - there is the answer

Comment: @UfguFugullu okay sir... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set my phpmyadmin user session to not time out so quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886740/how-to-set-my-phpmyadmin-user-session-to-not-time-out-so-quickly)

Comment: @Rabin sir sorry for that if it's duplicate but i don't find exactly solution so post . sorry for that sir... :)

Comment: @HardikChapla, PHPMyAdmin manage its own sessions time-out, and you can even have it per user IIRC. so your question is more about phpmyadmin and not about php default session clean up. for php own seesion clean up process there is cron job which run ~30 minutes, and you can find the session length with `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime`

Comment: @Rabin okay sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can change it from php.ini file. The default is 24 minutes (1440 seconds).

Here is an link hope this link helps you.
[max session time](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)

Or you can also chage it in php connection file.

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600); //Make it one hour
```

Comment: Thank You Sir for your help... :)

Comment: Welcome Hardik :)